# Serializer to create user and profile in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serializer to create a user and your profile at the same time.

My code:

#### serializers

```py
class UserProfileSerializer(
    serializers.ModelSerializer
):

    profile = ProfileSerializer(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super(UserProfileSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        user.save()
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ("groups", "user_permissions", )


 class UserSerializer(
    serializers.ModelSerializer
):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ("groups", "user_permissions", )
```

view

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    model = User

     def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == "POST":
            return UserProfileSerializer
        return UserProfileSerializer
```

My problem is the user... When I trying to create a user/profile I get this error:

```py
{
    "profile": {
        "user": [
            "This field must be unique."
        ]
    }
}
```